# iOS how to take user directly to the Wallet app

Tags: ios, applepay, wallet, human-interface

I'm integrating Apple Pay now and I see
iOS Human Interface Guidelines for Apple Pay.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/apple-pay/

[image: Set up Apple Pay Button]

How can I open the Wallet app when the user taps a button?

Comment: Hii Soft Dev . Did you find solution for this completely? I have the same issue.when ever user clicks the add cards to wallet then it directly to the wallet app  for add the cards. please suggest me.

Comment: @vijju Did you check the below answer?

Comment: For that, any special entitlements are needed from Apple. com.apple.developer.payment-pass-provisioning   is  this needed.

Comment: @vijju This post is for asking the way to open wallet app. And the answer I accepted works well.

Comment: okk. Thank you. i got it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out the `PKPaymentButton`. There are already pre-built buttons for this as part of PassKit.

```
let setupButton = PKPaymentButton(type: .setUp, style: .black)
```

More information can be found at the [PKPaymentButton Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/passkit/pkpaymentbutton).

**EDIT:**

`PKPassLibrary` can actually perform the action. You can use it like so:

```
let library = PKPassLibrary()
library.openPaymentSetup()
```

More information can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/passkit/pkpasslibrary).

**Note:** The above call will only work on a real iOS device.

Comment: it just supports UI only, doesn't it?

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. I'll update my answer momentarily.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see why it wouldn't. I will verify tonight.

Comment: Thanks! I will be waiting your reply.

Comment: Confirmed, this will not trigger anything on the simulator, and will work on a real iOS device.

Comment: Hii Mark .let library = PKPassLibrary()
library.openPaymentSetup(). is this libary display the apple wallet when user taps the add cards to wallet button.

Answer (score 1):

Code in Objective C, same as @Mark answer:

First you have to import PassKit:

```
@import PassKit;
```

And call func to open Wallet App, func:

```
-(void) openAppleWalletApp {
    PKPassLibrary * wallet = [[PKPassLibrary alloc] init];
    [wallet openPaymentSetup];
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, nice to see Objective-C is still alive, I love coding in it. Presumably Apple will eventually only support Swift?